# SQL Query with Total and Monthly breakdowns

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I write a proper SQL query in order to display the below output. The revenue as a percentage rounded up to the fourth decimal. Ex. If Sales person has generated $24K in total (2021)

I am using pgAdmin 4 (v4.12) and each time I try, I get either total of Monthly but not Yearly and vice versa.

This is my attempted query:

```
SELECT Person_id
     , MONTH(Date_of_Sales) AS month
     , YEAR(Date_of_Sales) AS year 
     , ROUND((Total_Revenue)/SUM(Total_Revenue),3) AS pct_rev
     , SUM(Total_Revenue) AS monthly_revenue
     , SUM(Total_Revenue) AS yearly_revenue 
WHERE Date_of_Sales >= '2021-01-01' and Date_of_Sales <='2021-12-31' 
GROUP BY Month(Date_of_Sales) 
ORDER BY Month(Date_of_Sales);
```

#### Expected Output

| Person_id | MONTH | % Revenue | Monthly Revenue | Yearly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65464654 | 2021-01 | 0.1667 | 2000 | 12000 |
| 65464654 | 2021-02 | 0.2500 | 3000 | 12000 |
| 65464654 | 2021-03 | 0.1667 | 2000 | 12000 |
| 65464655 | 2021-01 | 0.0208 | 500 | 24000 |
| 65464655 | 2021-03 | 0.1667 | 4000 | 24000 |

> **NOTE:** `% Revenue` is the *percentage* of the `Monthly Revenue` with respect to the `Yearly Revenue` for that *Sales Person*
>
> - *should be rounded to 4 decimal places!*

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
  Person_id BIGINT,
  Date_of_Sales timestamp,
  Total_Revenue int,
  "Type of Sale" VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! This looks like a simple `GROUP BY` application, but to properly answer in a way that you will be able to _implement_ rather than _interpret_ it helps to include the raw data that corresponds to your expected output and the related schema for the tables involved. Otherwise we need to make a lot of assumptions which will lead to a discussion rather than an answer.

Comment: Please Include your SQL statements that have the montly or the yearly, from that we can show you how to combine the concepts.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I am running postgreSQL

Comment: Yes, I see that from the tags, but what _version_? There are different language features in the runtime versions that change how to answer this question

Comment: Not sure if this helps. I am running it on pgAdmin 4 version 4.12

Comment: please show the query that gets you this: _Each time I try I get either total of Monthly_

Comment: I'm expecting to see the actual query, the `SELECT` statement, please post it in plain text though, images are too hard to interpret and are generally not accepted unless they demonstrate visual layout issues that are hard to describe in text. SQL **_IS_** text, so we try to use it when we can.

Comment: SELECT Person_id, MONTH(Date_of_Sales) AS month, YEAR(Date_of_Sales) AS year
ROUND((Total_Revenue)/SUM(Total_Revenue),3) AS pct_rev,
SUM(Total_Revenue)AS monthly_revenue,
SUM(Total_Revenue) AS yearly_revenue
WHERE Date_of_Sales >= '2021-01-01' and Date_of_Sales <='2021-12-31' 
GROUP BY Month(Date_of_Sales)
ORDER BY Month(Date_of_Sales);

Comment: Thankyou, I'll clean this up...

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this!

Comment: Last question, please explain the percentage logic in plain English, is that percent over all transactions for that month or year for all person's or just that person?

Comment: Essentially the % is Total Month Revenue / Total Year Revenue by month.  To see what was the % of monthly revenue.

Comment: I hope my explanation regarding that revenue % makes sense. I can try to explain it better if my earlier explanation wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Postgres does not have a `month()` function. What database are you **really** using? What does `select version();` show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with analysis like this, even if we constrain the total results to only 1 single year, we will still need to execute the query in 2 stages. There are all sorts of techniques to do this including the use of *[nested or inline queries](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/using-nested-select-in-postgres-sql-804)*, [CTEs *(Common Table Expressions)*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-cte/), [Lateral Joins (AKA CROSS APPLY)](https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/11140/cross-apply---lateral-join) and we can even use [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html). But we must first understand the distinct resultsets that are required to produce your `Monthly Revenue` and `Yearly Revenue`

> You learn to skip the first principals and just jump into the solution later, I find the using CTEs to declare the individual components makes this example easier to maintain and understand, especially given that we need to re-use the aggregate expression in the `% Revenue` column.

```
WITH MonthlyRevenue AS
(
  SELECT Person_id
       , DATE_TRUNC('Month', Date_of_Sales) AS MONTH
       , SUM (Total_Revenue) AS "Monthly Revenue"
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY Person_Id, DATE_TRUNC('Month', Date_of_Sales) 
),
YearlyRevenue AS
(
  SELECT Person_id
       , DATE_TRUNC('Year', Date_of_Sales) AS Year
       , SUM (Total_Revenue) AS "Yearly Revenue"
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY Person_Id, DATE_TRUNC('Year', Date_of_Sales) 
)
SELECT m.Person_id
     , to_char(m.MONTH,'YYYY-MM') as MONTH
     , ROUND(CAST(m."Monthly Revenue" as numeric) / CAST(y."Yearly Revenue" as numeric),4) AS "% Revenue"
     , m."Monthly Revenue"
     , y."Yearly Revenue"
FROM MonthlyRevenue m
INNER JOIN YearlyRevenue y ON  m.Person_id = y.Person_id 
                           AND DATE_TRUNC('Year', m.MONTH) = y.Year
ORDER BY m.Person_id, m.MONTH
```

as the `YearlyRevenue` Result Set can be expressed as an aggregate of the `MonthlyRevenue` query, we can use a *Window Function* instead of joining the two recordsets, this would have a different performance profile to the previous query.

```
WITH MonthlyRevenue AS
(
  SELECT Person_id
       , DATE_TRUNC('Month', Date_of_Sales) AS MONTH
       , SUM (Total_Revenue) AS "Monthly Revenue"
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY Person_Id, DATE_TRUNC('Month', Date_of_Sales) 
)
SELECT m.Person_id
     , to_char(m.MONTH,'YYYY-MM') as MONTH
     , ROUND(CAST(m."Monthly Revenue" as numeric) / CAST(SUM(m."Monthly Revenue")
       OVER (PARTITION BY m.Person_id, DATE_TRUNC('Year', m.MONTH)) as numeric),4) AS "% Revenue"
     , m."Monthly Revenue"
     , SUM(m."Monthly Revenue")
       OVER (PARTITION BY m.Person_id, DATE_TRUNC('Year', m.MONTH)) as "Yearly Revenue"
FROM MonthlyRevenue m
WHERE m.MONTH BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
ORDER BY m.Person_id, m.MONTH;
```

*[See this fiddle prepared with a fictitious dataset.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/inoSdqhtmxEF9Skf9dqTWe/0)*

---

There are many other ways to re-write the same query, usually we want a query that provides the optimal performance. But performance isn't a function of your query syntax alone, it will depend on the indexing, fragmentation and the size and distribution of the data. What works well in one schema may easily be out-performed by a different query in a similar but different schema. There is considerable cost in maintenance of code and algorithms, so readability and how easy it is for you to understand and maintain are other factors to include, which is why I showcase for you today multiple options.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the detailed explanation! I will make sure to study up on this. Very much appreciated by a newbie like myself.

Comment: No thanks needed, just up votes ;)